# Unexpected Value While using Bubble Sort in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

When using the bubble sort method to sort my array from smallest to largest its outputting an unexpected value of: -858993460.

Within the debugger i'm being prompted with "Stack around variable 'numb was corrupted'.

I'm currently using Visual studios to run the code.

I have also ran the same code within a new project with no results.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int length = 6;   
    int temp = 0;     
    int end = 6;
    int numb[] = { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for (int counter = length - 1; counter > 0; counter--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
        {
            if (numb[i] > numb[i + 1])
            {
                temp = numb[i + 1];
                numb[i + 1] = numb[i];
                numb[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            std::cout << numb[i] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
        end--;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Think about `numb[i + 1]` when `i == 5`.

Comment: you should learn to use the VS excellent debugger to step through your code, watch what happens to all the variables, etc.

Comment: Where would you suggest on finding info on learning the vs debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you inner `for` loop where `int i = 0; i < end; i++`, you need to set the condition to be `i < end - 1`. This is because you are already going to be at the end of the array with `i + 1` when swapping the indexes around.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that the reason its changed to "end -1" is due to the reason numb counts from 0-5. p.s. sorry if i sound silly its due to the fact am still learning c++

Comment: Yes. When `i` is at 5, you try to access `numb[i + 1]` which is not an index you should be accessing. It is a valid move, however, you did not define it as anything, thus it could be used by something else. When you have `end - 1`, you only go up to `i = 4`, allowing for `i + 1` to be at the last index of the array.